# Are there any issues with this network setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have setup my house from which I run 3 business, host servers etc. I setup lots of outlets for wired network 20 years ago. I later added Wifi.

I do not know enough about networking to spot potential issues, and I sometimes have weird networking issue like VOIP devices disconnecting, printer not accessible etc. I want to know, if there is something fundamentally wrong with my design that could cause issues.

Some specific questions:

1. is it OK that there are two switches? Especially that LAN cable connecting the switches is rather long (~ 60 feet).
2. is it OK that the 2nd floor wifi access points is connected to the 2nd switch and not directly to the modem/router?
3. can there be an issue with a computer from 2nd floor, connecting to computer on wifi network in the basement? Thus having to go through 2 switches?

3.1) is it possible, in such a case, that the connection from 2nd floor will somehow not know how to be routed to computer in basement?

4. I am only getting 2MB/s transfer rate for any device on the WIFI network, but ~10BM/s on  devices connected via LAN cable (switches are 10/100 mbps). I would expect my wifi performance to be better, but I know it could be normal. However, is there anything in my network architecture that could be the cause of this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: How many hosts within this LAN are we talking about here? ISP router(+modem) can sometime be too "cheap" to handle too many hosts / IPs, I think. But other than that case, avoiding additional layer(s) of NAT is generally considered a good practice.

Comment: @TomYan I do not think I am reaching host limit. I think I got about ~ 30 devices total.

Comment: You write " I sometimes have weird networking issue like VOIP devices disconnecting, printer not accessible etc" <--  You could troubleshoot that  e.g. what if the VOIP device is on a different floor..  what if it's connected to a different laptop. What about other VOIP devices.  You write "(switches are 10/100 mbps" <-- I'd use Gigabit ethernet switches nowadays not 10/100Mbps.. WiFi will be the bottleneck but at least when wired you'd get better speed with Gigabit Ethernet switches. Gigabit ethernet switches are not expensive(thoguh I haven't tried one with 20 ports!)

Comment: also if you are using a wireless access point connected to a switch then the switch doesn't have to have 20 ports.. so you could try a Gigabit ethernet switch. with less ports that isn't that expensive.. Cables can go wrong.. get a cable with a rugged jacket, they tend to be better quality in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the setup looks fine.

Length of cables are not an issue (even total length).

Make sure devices are connected LAN to LAN and that the DCHP server you show is the only DHCP server - that is, do not let any other device be a DHCP server.

Make sure everything is on one subnet.  This certainly facilitates network printing.

Make sure devices and printers have static IP addresses to prevent getting lost in case of a power failure or network restart.

That way all devices will be able to see all other devices (assuming you want this at the device level).

Any device (server) facing the Internet (web server) will have to be set up and secured separately. The above in my post is for the internal business requirements.

I come pretty close to doing this. Modem, Router in basement, main computer (wired) on main floor, printer on main floor, Ubqiquiti AP and wireless laptops in upstairs office.

Phone roam throughout the home.